# Is it possible to restrict max window size windows 8.1 or 10?

Tags: windows-8, display

Basically I have a 4k 43 inch monitor, and I don't really need most apps to ever open "maximized"  I'd rather be able to set "maximize" to only do 1920x1080 or something similar. I did a little googling, and everything I found was about writing software, where the programmer wants to restrict the size of their specific app.

Answer (score 2):

I found two possible solutions.

1. You could change the default window size on a **per application** basis.

> [To force Windows to record the size of a window and set it as the default size for that program each time it's opened, simply re-size the window to your preferred size, then depress and hold the CTRL key while you click the red X to close it. The program should use that size as the default size until changed.](http://help.wfu.edu/public/computers/standard-load-software/windows-7---set-default-window-size)

2. I found this software called [MaxMax](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/25/change-the-maximize-window-size/). Apparently the developer no longer exists but this site has saved a copy of the program that you can download. It's pretty old and I'm not sure what versions of Windows it supports (it claims 32-bit and 64-bit Windows but doesn't give a specific version).

This one **does not** to do exactly what you want though. It allows you to set limits on the top, bottom, left, and right sides of the screen, but does not limit application window size specifically.

Comment: This is the same behavior without holding ctrl

Comment: Regarding MaxMax - I'm the developer of this application. My website is back: http://mthings.net There are MaxMax and my other tools. Next version of MaxMax (which is being developed) will allow to use per application margins. You can always contact me using e-mail provided on the site.

Comment: @MVCylon: It seems to me that, *sometimes*, (Ctrl)+⌧ is different from plain ⌧; I'm not sure when.  But, even when it works, it sets only the *normal* size of the application's window, not its maximized size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. Fancy Zones - Microsoft Powertoy
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/wiki/FancyZones-Overview